# Is there a Powershell way to convert evt to csv?

Tags: powershell

I have many log files from legacy Operating Systems that need to be converted to csv. Is there a way to do this using Powershell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [`Get-WinEvent`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-7.2)

```
Get-WinEvent -Path C:\somewhere\foo.evt | Export-CSV C:\somewhere\foo.csv
```

If you want to look at the csv in excel, I would add `-delimiter ';'` to the `Export-CSV` for readability.

This works for `.evt`, `.evtx`, and `.etl` file name extensions. You can include different files and file types in the same command (`-Path` accepts an array of filepaths).

Comment: This mechanism hides a lot of data behind nested objects. If you're looking for event description text (like finding out that someone is changing firewall configurations through group policy updates *14* times a day) this needs a little more parsing -- at least with the current powershell.

Answer (score 1):

easier way would be

```
$logparser = "c:\program files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\logparser.exe"
$query = "SELECT * INTO c:\logs\sample.csv FROM c:\logs\sample.evtx"

& $logparser -i:evt -o:csv $query
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain your answer.

Comment: For my purposes it gave me a start... Getting it so that it was 100% readable? Well, luckily cygwin sed comes to the rescue. That takes EVERY event record in that event log and drops it into the csv file. It prepends the event entry with the event file name, and prints the date 2x, and some other issues. But it was enough to get me what I needed without waiting a week for the event viewer to dump the csv file...